# Got an error creating the test database: Django unittest

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

When I run `python manage.py test`, django is asking a strange question each time:

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'nyble'@'localhost' to database 'test_nybledb'")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_nybledb', or 'no' to cancel:
```

I was expecting it to just delete and remake a basic sqlite3 DB, and I don't want this behavior.

Whether I say yes or no it just exits tests:

```
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error recreating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'nyble'@'localhost' to database 'test_nybledb'")
```

In settings I have

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'nybledb',
        'USER': 'nyble',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

How can I stop this and make it use normal sqlite3 db during running tests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set this up in settings.py. It says that if there is 'test' in the command line input, use sqlite as db engine.

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv or 'test_coverage' in sys.argv: #Covers regular testing and django-coverage
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
```

Comment: thanks you this is very useful.you just saved me.God bless You )))