# Django testing: Got an error creating the test database: database "database_name" already exists

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have a problem with testing. It's my first time writing tests and I have a problem.

I just created a test folder inside my app `users`, and `test_urls.py` for testing the urls.

When I type:

`python manage.py test users`

It says:

> Creating test database for alias 'default'... Got an error creating
>   the test database: database "database_name" already exists
>
> Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database
>   'database_name', or 'no' to cancel:

What does it mean? What happens if I type yes? Do I lose all my data in database?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47466185

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When testing, Django creates a test database to work on so that your development database is not polluted. The error message says that Django is trying to create a test database named `"database_name"` and that this database already exists. You should check the tables of the database software you are using and check what is in `database_name`, it's probably been created by mistake.

If you type yes, the database `database_name` will be deleted and it is **unlikely that you will be able to recover the data**. So try to understand what is going on first.

You should set the name of the test database in `settings.py`. There is a specific [`TEST` dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#test) in the `DATABASE` settings for this:

`settings.py`

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'mytestdatabase',
        },
    },
}
...
```

By default, the prefix `test_` is added to the name of your development database. You should check your `settings.py` to check what is going on.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database):

> The default test database names are created by prepending `test_` to the value of each `NAME` in `DATABASES`. When using SQLite, the tests will use an in-memory database by default (i.e., the database will be created in memory, bypassing the filesystem entirely!). The `TEST` dictionary in `DATABASES` offers a number of settings to configure your test database. For example, if you want to use a different database name, specify NAME in the `TEST` dictionary for any given database in `DATABASES`.

Comment: If I'm using a connection string, like `'default': 'postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/db'`, how do I specify the TEST?

Comment: @KhoPhi the last `db` is the name of the database.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in the event that you get such a warning when using the `--keepdb` argument such as

```
python manage.py test --keepdb [appname]
```

then this would typically mean that multiple instances of the `Client` were instantiated, perhaps one per test. The solution is to create one client for the test class and refer to it in all corresponding methods like so:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_one(self):
        response = self.client.get('/path/one/')
        # assertions

    def test_two(self):
        response = self.client.post('/path/two/', {'some': 'data'})
        # assertions
```

You could also (unverified) create a static client using the `setUpClass` class method.